# function taking in an input image and different kernel size

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have this filtering function that takes an input image, performs convolution using a given kernel, and returns the resulting image. However, I can't seem to work it out how to make it takes different kernel sizes.For example instead of pre-defined 3x3 kernel as below in the code, it could instead take 5x5 or 7x7. and then the user could input the type of kernel/filter they want(Depending on the intended effect). I can't seem to put my head around it. i'm quite new to matlab.

```
function [newImg] = kernelFunc(imgB)


img=imread(imgB);

figure,imshow(img); 




img2=zeros(size(img)+2);

newImg=zeros(size(img));




for rgb=1:3

        for x=1:size(img,1)

            for y=1:size(img,2)

                img2(x+1,y+1,rgb)=img(x,y,rgb);

            end

        end

end


for rgb=1:3
    for i= 1:size(img2,1)-2

        for j=1:size(img2,2)-2

            window=zeros(9,1);

            inc=1;

            for x=1:3

                for y=1:3

                    window(inc)=img2(i+x-1,j+y-1,rgb);

                    inc=inc+1;

                end

            end

           kernel=[1;2;1;2;4;2;1;2;1]/16;



            med=window.*kernel;

            disp(med);

            med=sum(med);

            med=floor(med);


            newImg(i,j,rgb)=med;



        end

    end

end


newImg=uint8(newImg);

figure,imshow(newImg);

end
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `conv2`? http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html

Answer (score 0):

I have commented the code and marked the places to change `<--`.  `kernel` in this example is a column vector of 3*3=9 elements.  Besides changing the kernel itself, you may also need to change the amount of zero-padding around the image.  E.g., for a 5x5 kernel, you would need two rows and two columns of padding instead of one.  Then update the inner loop I have marked "grab each pixel" to pull an area the size of the kernel (e.g., `for x=1:5` and `for y=1:5` for a 5x5 kernel).  The actual convolution is unchanged.

Reminder: the function is taking a `uint8` (0..255-valued) RGB image.  `window` and `kernel` are `double`, so the `trunc` cuts any fractional part off before putting the new pixel value in `uint8 newImg`.

```
function [newImg] = kernelFunc(imgB)

img=imread(imgB);
figure,imshow(img); 

img2=zeros(size(img)+2);  % one extra column on each side, and one extra
                          % row top and bottom. <-- May need more padding.
newImg=zeros(size(img));    % the destination

% Pad the image with zeros at the left and top (transform img->img2)
for rgb=1:3
    for x=1:size(img,1) %for each row
        for y=1:size(img,2) %for each column
            img2(x+1,y+1,rgb)=img(x,y,rgb);    % <-- adjust per kernel size
        end
    end
end

% Process the padded image (img2->newImg)
for rgb=1:3
    for i= 1:size(img2,1)-2         % for each row
        for j=1:size(img2,2)-2      % for each column

            % Build a row vector of the pixels to be convolved.
            window=zeros(9,1);      % <-- 9=kernel size
            inc=1;
            for x=1:3               % <-- grab each pixel 
                for y=1:3           % <-- under the kernel
                    window(inc)=img2(i+x-1,j+y-1,rgb);
                    inc=inc+1;
                end
            end

            kernel=[1;2;1;2;4;2;1;2;1]/16;  % <-- the kernel itself

            med=window.*kernel;     % start the convolution
            disp(med);
            med=sum(med);           % finish the convolution
            med=floor(med);         % fit the pixels back into uint8.

            newImg(i,j,rgb)=med;    % store the result

        end %for each column
    end %for each row
end %for each color channel


newImg=uint8(newImg);
figure,imshow(newImg);

end
```